# Android:Issue Image resolution

Tags: java, android, imageview, resolution

Problem occurs while using high resolution image in device.

```
 imageview a;
InputStream ims = getAssets().open("sam.png");//sam.png=520*1400 device=320*480 or 480*800
Drawable d=Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
a.setLayoutParams(new        LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
a.setImageDrawable(d);
```

by using above code image leaves spaces on top and bottom to next contents or If I shrink an image by giving fixed px, its get blur image on its size. Anyway to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `Bitmap` instead of `Drawable`:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
a.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Looks like Android doing some tricks with drawables, depending of screen density.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following solution helps.
You can make your imageView of fixed size and pass that imageView's width and height to `calculateInSampleSize` method. Based on image size, it will decide whether to down sample the image or not.

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, final String imagePath)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try
    {
        inputStream = assetManager.open(imagePath);         

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = true;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    }
    catch(Exception exception) 
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        bitmap = null;
    }

    return bitmap;
}


public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, final int requiredWidth, final int requiredHeight) 
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(height > requiredHeight || width > requiredWidth) 
    {
        if(width > height) 
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)requiredHeight);
        } 
        else 
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)requiredWidth);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: what does mean 
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth; and how to define?

Comment: those are width and height of bitmap used to compare with imageView width and height.

Comment: There is some mistaake in your code, you define some options but never use them. Look at the official documentation that now exists: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @Vince options is used. Have a clear look at the code.

Comment: I meant to decode the stream. My code looks like using BitMapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options). In your code, you read and write the options but never apply them to anything (at least I cannot see where).

Comment: @Vince I am using `options` to get the `inSampleSize` value to be considered while decoding. Its not compulsory to use `options` while decoding.