# When loading bitmap with "BitmapFactory.decodeResource" app crashes

Tags: android, bitmap, crash, loading

I'm developing a game for little children, which contains different educative exercises.
In one of them I need a picture background, so I'm loading it and scale it with Matrix to fill screen. But sometimes loading picture causes crash.

```
public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Resources resources, float screen_x_max, float screen_y_max){
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    screenWidth=screen_x_max;
    screenHeight=screen_y_max;
    // picture for bg
    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.background);
    ...
}
```

At the end of this thread I recycle it and null.

```
if (this.picture!=null)
    {
        this.picture.recycle();
        this.picture=null;
    }
```

But app still crases. There is error log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:494)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:393)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:419)
at lexu.me.childstudy_lite.DrawThreadFindAnimals2.<init>(findAnimals2.java:271)
at lexu.me.childstudy_lite.findanimals2_view.surfaceCreated(findAnimals2.java:186)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:548)
at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:353)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to load a very large bitmap and downscale it with a matrix?  The very large bitmap will use a very large amount of memory when decoded. Start with appropriately scaled bitmaps, using the various drawable folders (e.g. drawable-hdpi) to load images with a proper initial scale.

Comment: yes, it quite large: 1200*800 (344 kB).

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem on Android.
This should provide you with plenty of tips and approaches :

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

By down sampling bitmap, you can avoid OME. Have a look at following link. Hope it helps.

[Android:Issue Image resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949234/androidissue-image-resolution/11949665#11949665)

**Edit:** In that link, its taking images from Asset folder. You can modify it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an Out Of Memory Exception. To avoid this, have a look at this link:
[android how to handle out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544919/android-how-to-handle-out-of-memory-exception)

There is a ton of information on the web that will help you with this problem.

I hope this helps.