# Out of memory exception for static images used in application

Tags: android

Let's say i have 10 activities, and each contain a static image, I am finishing and starting a new activity on left and right click of the arrow.[image]

Images are in drawable folder and are a bit large size, As far as i think, if a activity finishes then all the memory it's using  is freed(that's why i had taken so many activities), but it's not happening.

If constantly go on clicking the right and left button, the app freezes and crashes(out of memory exception).

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949234/androidissue-image-resolution/11949665#11949665. With the help of this, to some extent you can avoid OME

Comment: what does "static image" means for you?

Comment: static means thos are not downloaded from any url its present in the drawable folder of the project and set in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Load your images using:

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, opts);`

Use inSampleSize in `Options` to rescale your image.

2- Recycle your bitmap in `onDestroy()`.